# How to get Power Control Widget (Status bar widget) on stock rom

Tags: app-widgets, notification-bar

Can I have the Power Control Widget (Status bar widget) from CM7 on the Stock ROM?

[image: Power Control Widgets on Status Bar]

This is the is the only feature I missed from CM7 when I switched back to Stock ROM.
It gives the quick access to power widgets when when I pull down my notification bar
I've tried ExtendedControls but its buggy and not as flexible as Power Control Widget.

Is there any way to have the Power Control Widget on Stock ROM?

Comment: On what stock ROM? Which device?

Answer (score 2):

Stock ROMs for some handsets from some manufacturers actually include such a widget.  For example, Samsung's TouchWiz overlay provides a similar looking functionality, although not as configurable or flexible as the one from CyanogenMod ROM.

For other stock ROMs that don't have this feature built-in, 3rd-party apps (like the one you already tried) are the only options.  Even if your device is rooted, porting this widget from CM is not an easy task, since it heavily relies on changes to Android framework and other core services that are specific to CM.  In other words, by the time you're done porting all the prerequisites, you'd end up running CM anyways.

Comment: I have a rooted mobile. There should be some way to get this widget ported on stock. Can you tell me which file in the ROM has the statusbar ui ? Can i replace this file with the CM7 version of the file to get this work ?

Comment: It's not as easy as replacing a few files.  Widget requires changes to Notification pull-down code and Settings, that in turn require code changes to the core framework, etc., possibly all the way down to kernel.  Again, by the time you're done porting everything over, you will end up running CM.

Comment: You can do this via simple apps (like the previous app TogglePanel) however for anything Pre-ICS, it has to be part of system directly, so if your stock rom doesn't have one, you'll need a custom rom that does.  Again this is if you specifically want it in the notification pulldown.

Answer (score 2):

You can try https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.seifsoft.togglepanel
It's pretty and quite customizable.
You can always flash another ROM, but TogglePanel is a viable (in my opinion) alternative.